# How to show seconds on the clock in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome-shell, time, clock

Is it possible to show the seconds on the clock in GNOME 3?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The GUI way to do this, (on 22.04 LTS) seems to be:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Before 20.04 LTS the package name was different:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

and then launch "Tweaks" either by searching for it in Applications menu or launching `gnome-tweaks` from terminal.

From there you'll see something like this:

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool - Top Bar seconds adjustment]

Comment: ugh. having to install a separate tool isn't "user-friendly" in my mind.

Comment: @Michael so you better want to put strange things on Terminal?

Answer (score 190):

Not sure when this path changed, but as of Ubuntu 13.04 the seconds display can be set in the terminal with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
```

To turn seconds display off:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds false
```

and checked with:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds
```

Comment: For those who prefer the GUI way, @MichelSamia gives another answer based on gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: At first it did not work on my Debian 9. It gave: `(process:23119): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`. I checked the value of `$DISPLAY` and it was blank! So I started a new terminal, `$DISPLAY` was `:0` and this time it worked.

Comment: Works in Fedora 32 as well

Comment: Works on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: not working. Do I need to restart ?

Comment: Did not work on Ubuntu 18.04.5 w/ GNOME 3.28.2 but the Riki137's answer did.

Comment: Worked for me on the beta of Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: This option didn't work for me on Ubuntu 22.04 (at least without a restart), but using gnome-tweaks did (see Michel Samia's answer and JoyfulPanda's comment).

Comment: This still working on ubuntu 23.04 without reboot

Answer (score 54):

GUI way:

1. launch gnome-tweak-tool, sometimes called Advanced Settings
2. click the Top Bar menu
3. enable Show seconds

Comment: I found this on my new RHEL 7 VM was called "Tweaks". It was a separate application from "Settings".

Comment: `gnome-tweak-tool` is changed to now `gnome-tweaks`.

Comment: Worked great for me on Ubuntu 22.02 (using gnome-tweaks instead of gnome-tweak).

Answer (score 17):

Yes, run this command in a *Terminal*:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.clock show-seconds true
```

And you can verify with:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.clock show-seconds
```

Or you can install [dconf-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools] and use `dconf-editor` to browse to `org.gnome.shell.clock`

Comment: No such schema 'org.gnome.shell.clock' → `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true`

Answer (score 3):

For **MATE Desktop** (the continuation and fork of GNOME 2 with GTK+ 3 support), you can achieve this using the graphical user interface (GUI)!

- Right-click on date and time:
  [image]
- Go to `Preferences`
- Now enable the `Show seconds`
  [image]

The end result:
[image]

Drink beer and Vote me up, cause it rocks!